# create OleFile type file from uploaded file

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I am using `Message` class from [this repo](https://github.com/mattgwwalker/msg-extractor/blob/master/ExtractMsg.py) to parse `.msg` file. I have a test file that works with that class.

I am trying to use that class in custom parser I am writing for my Django rest framework app.

But when I read `stream.body`, it additionally adds the following content

```
    ----------------------------488071469102781097692083
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="email_test.msg"
    Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-outlook  

   < actual content here >

    ----------------------------488071469102781097692083--
```

and I have a doubt that, because of this additional content, `Message` class is throwing following error.

```
not an OLE2 structured storage file
```

Is my doubt right? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

msg-extractor is for .msg files from MS Outlook, which have a binary format called "OLE2" or "CFB". They start with "D0CF" when you open them in a hex viewer.

The snippet in your question looks like a MIME-encoded e-mail, which is text.

Are you sure the file you are trying to parse is a MS Outlook MSG file?

Comment: Thanks a lot Decalage for your reply. Yes it is msg file. Same file works if I directly pass to Message class in shell.

Comment: I think I got a hint from your answer. The browser is adding that content because I might have setting wrong content-type in request.

Comment: Decalage, my guess was right, it was `content-type` in a request I was sending. Thank you for your hint.